# python3 string encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, python-3.x, pyqt

What I'm trying to do is to ask for password when user tries to close application. I stored the password in a text file for now. But even if I enter the correct password application won't close and is saying that I have entered wrong password(prints IGNORE1). I tried different encodings of file with password but nothing worked. Encoding of file is UTF-8

```
  def closeEvent(self, event):
    heslo_zadane = self.showDialog()
    in_file = open("klient.cfg", "rt")
    main_heslo = in_file.read()
    in_file.close()
    if heslo_zadane[1] == True:
      if heslo_zadane[0] == main_heslo:
        event.accept()
      else:
        event.ignore()
    else:
      event.ignore()

  def showDialog(self):
    text, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Vypnutie Klienta', 
        'Zadajte správcovské heslo:')
    return text, ok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there maybe a line ending on the password in the file? Otherwise it should work.

Comment: Yes you are right I created file through gedit and it added Unix/Linux Line Ending so I used main_heslo.rstrip() and it works now. Thanks for pointing that out.